# Getting logger and configuration from Dependency Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

As you can tell from this question I’m still a newbie with .Net Core and understanding about Dependency Injection.

I’m in the process of writing a .Net Core Console app and I was finally able to get to a point where I’m doing a little bit of DI for logging and configuration settings. What I’m not understanding is using DI when calling another class from within a class.

I created a class called AppHost which has a function called Run() in it. In my Program.cs I’ve setup DI and then will call the AppHost.Run() to execute my main code.

Inside of my AppHost I need to call some database functions in another file I’ve called Data/DataManager. My understanding was that I would setup the class in the DI container and would be able to get my logging and configuration from there. As far as I know, I’ve done that in my “host” declaration. However, when I call my DataManager.GetActiveEmployees() it’s wanting me to create an object since my DataManager is not set a static. When I create a DataManager object it is wanting me to pass in my logger and configuration since that is what is in the constructor of the class. I can do that but is sure seems like that is not the correct way to do it. I thought with DI I would be able to get the logger and configuration out of DI and not need to pass it into the object? Am I supposed to create the DataManager object and pass the logger and configuration from my AppHost into it?

Program.cs

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder().ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddTransient<IAppHost, AppHost>();
                    services.AddTransient<IFileManager, FileManager>();
                    services.AddTransient<IDataManager, DataManager>();

                    services.AddLogging(builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AddNLog("nlog.config");
                    });
                }).Build();

var svc = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<AppHost>(host.Services);
svc.Run();
```

AppHost.cs

```
private void CheckEmailAddresses()
{
DataManager oDataManager = new DataManager();

var listEmployees = new List<Employee>();
listEmployees = oDataManager.GetActiveEmployees();
}
```

DataManager.cs

```
public class DataManager : IDataManager
    {
        private readonly ILogger<DataManager> _log;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public DataManager(ILogger<DataManager> log, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _log = log;
            _configuration = config;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already registered your IDataManager in DI dependency. So, instead of doing `new` which killing the purpose of DI anyway you need to change your `CheckEmailAddresses` like this.

```
private void YouClassName()
{
 private readonly IDataManager _dataManager;
 public YouClassName(IDataManager dataManager)
 {
   _dataManager = dataManger.
 }

 private void CheckEmailAddresses()
 {
   var listEmployees = new List<Employee>();
   listEmployees = _dataManager.GetActiveEmployees();
 }
}
```

Now we are inject `IDataManager` into your class and your other dependencies like `Logger` will be build automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Makes a bit more sense seeing that. I injected my DataManager and FileManager into my AppHost class to be able to access them. It didn't make sense from the little that I know about DI to create a New DataManager() and then have to pass in the logging and configuration. That's why I wanted to reach out for a little explanation and this helped. Hopefully it helps someone else down the road as well.